# How can I turn off numbering for figures?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

#### MWE

```
#+CAPTION: Lisp is a language of timeless elegance.
https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/lisp_cycles.png
```

Export as HTML will look something like this (depending on CSS):

[image: output]

I just want

> *Lisp is a language of timeless elegance*

to appear under the image.  How can I get rid of the numbering?

Answer (score 10):

You may not be able to easily influence the Org export itself, but you can still remove the figure number with some CSS:

```css
.figure-number {
    display: none;
}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Clever.  Note that this does get rid of both "Figure: " and the number...

Comment: @wasamasa Yep, which is what I wanted in the original question =)

Comment: Ah, I did read it too quickly to notice.

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid you can't influence this in the HTML export (as opposed to the LaTeX export which allows adding arbitrary captioning code) because the behaviour is hardcoded in Org's `org-html-paragraph`:

```
(if (not (org-string-nw-p raw)) raw
  (concat
   "<span class=\"figure-number\">"
   (format (org-html--translate "Figure %d:" info)
           (org-export-get-ordinal
            (org-element-map paragraph 'link
              'identity info t)
            info nil 'org-html-standalone-image-p))
   "</span> " raw))
```

Therefore, the only alternative I can imagine is using raw HTML:

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
<div class="figure">
<p><img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/lisp_cycles.png" /></p>
<p>Lisp is a language of timeless elegance</p>
</div>
#+END_HTML
```

Did you consider handing in a bug report with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`?

Comment: I'll consider it – this is definitely something that should be configurable from an Org-ish workflow – but I'll draw attention to the workaround in my answer =)

Answer (score 3):

Building on Sean Allred's answer, this worked great for me (no need to link to / tweak external style sheet, e.g. for a one-off use):

```
@@html:
<style>
.figure-number {
    display: none;
}
</style>
@@

#+CAPTION: Lisp is a language of timeless elegance.
https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/lisp_cycles.png
```