# İmage caption problem

Tags: images, org-publish

I use org-mode publish, and it all works great but I have this small problem. I use this format to insert images:

```
#+CAPTION: Cavendish deneyinin özgün analizi                                        
#+ATTR_HTML: :alt cavendish deneyi  :title cavendish deneyi :align center           
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 50% :height 50%
http://cavendish-deneyi.com/img/cavendish-memoirs-88.jpeg
```

But for some reason, "Figure 1" is added to the caption of every image I insert. Do you know why? How can I get rid of it? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I turn off numbering for figures?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17619/how-can-i-turn-off-numbering-for-figures)

Comment: Yes. I linked to that question in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that's where I got the link :-) - for which I thank you! Basically, marking the question as a duplicate (as I did) generates that comment/question. Marking questions as duplicates is part of the janitorial aspects of keeping the site healthy.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17619/how-can-i-turn-off-numbering-for-figures) solved the problem.

I added this

```
.figure-number {
    display: none;
}
```

to my css file.

**Edit:** More info about how I figured this:

I opened the page with the image that displayed "Figure 1." and in *Chrome DevTools*, I selected the caption and I saw that
there was a class called "figure-number":

```
<span class="figure-number">Figure 1: </span>
```

So this class was adding the "Figure 1." In my CSS file I added

```
.figure-number {
    display: none;
}
```

and that solved the problem.

Comment: I edited my answer with more info.